# Adding a value to a JButton's location

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

If I've created a JButton using Swing (named butOne), and want the button to move say, 10 pixels to the right when clicked, do I have an alternative other than:

`butOne.setLocation(butOne.getX() + 10, butOne.getY())` ?

Something akin to Visual Basic's `butOne.left -= 10` perhaps? It seems a very inconvenient workaround to get the X coordinate and the Y coordinate merely to change one. Thanks.

Comment: As much as I appreciate your venomous response, it's an example that I'm interested in for a general case rather than anything specifically.

Comment: *"..venomous response.."*  Seems like an appropriate response to a venomous GUI.

Comment: Since you should use the layout manager (not set absolute locations), I would suggest you change margin on butOne .setMargin(...), to achive the venomous GUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems a very inconvenient workaround to get the X coordinate and the Y coordinate merely to change one.

Seriously? Every language does things differently. Don't expect the methods to map one to one.

> do I have an alternative other than:

You can also create yourself some utility classes to do common functions that you are use to using:

```
public class Basic
{
    public static void moveLeft(Component component, int offset)
    {
        component.setLocation(component.getX() - offset, component.getY());
    }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
Basic.moveLeft(button1, 10);
```